# How do you perform arithmetic on selected columns using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data frame:

```
df <- structure(list(gene_id = c("ATP1B1", "CYCS", "DDX5", "GNB2L1", 
"PRR11"), BoneMarrow = c(0, 0, 0, 31138, 2703), Pulmonary = c(3380, 
21223.3333333333, 0, 0, 0), Umbilical = c(233, 0, 15397, 0, 0
)), .Names = c("gene_id", "BoneMarrow", "Pulmonary", "Umbilical"
), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), vars = "gene_id", labels = structure(list(gene_id = c("ATP1B1", 
"CYCS", "DDX5", "GNB2L1", "PRR11")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), vars = "gene_id", drop = TRUE, .Names = "gene_id"), indices = list(
    0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), drop = TRUE, group_sizes = c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), biggest_group_size = 1L)
df
```

Which looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   gene_id [5]
  gene_id BoneMarrow Pulmonary Umbilical
    <chr>      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1  ATP1B1          0   3380.00       233
2    CYCS          0  21223.33         0
3    DDX5          0      0.00     15397
4  GNB2L1      31138      0.00         0
5   PRR11       2703      0.00         0
```

I can do the following with base approach:

```
ndf <- as.data.frame(df)
rownames(ndf) <- df$gene_id
ndf$gene_id <- NULL
ndf <- ndf + 1
ndf
```

to get this:

```
       BoneMarrow Pulmonary Umbilical
ATP1B1          1   3381.00       234
CYCS            1  21224.33         1
DDX5            1      1.00     15398
GNB2L1      31139      1.00         1
PRR11        2704      1.00         1
```

How can I do that with dplyr chain?

Comment: Do u want the `rownames` as well?

Comment: @akrun yes I want it.

Comment: You cannot set `rownames` on tibble

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `mutate_if` to target and add 1 to all numeric variables. The `tibble` function `column_to_rownames` can then be applied after converting the tibble to data frame, i.e.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
 mutate_if(is.numeric, funs(. + 1)) %>% 
 as.data.frame() %>% 
 column_to_rownames(var = 'gene_id')
```

Which gives,

> ```
>       BoneMarrow Pulmonary Umbilical
> ATP1B1          1   3381.00       234
> CYCS            1  21224.33         1
> DDX5            1      1.00     15398
> GNB2L1      31139      1.00         1
> PRR11        2704      1.00         1
> ```

Comment: I need to perform arithmetic `plus 1` for all values.

Comment: sorry missed that. Edited

Answer (score 2):

We can do

```
df %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(-one_of('gene_id')), funs(.+1))  %>%
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  `row.names<-`(.[[1]]) %>% 
  select(-1)
#          BoneMarrow Pulmonary Umbilical
#ATP1B1          1   3381.00       234
#CYCS            1  21224.33         1
#DDX5            1      1.00     15398
#GNB2L1      31139      1.00         1
#PRR11        2704      1.00         1
```

Comment: since I have many columns other than `BoneMarrow", "Pulmonary", "Umbilical` . Can we just negate `gene_id` in the mutate?

Comment: I get the warning message ``Unknown variables: `gene_id` `

Comment: @neversaint  You can ignore the warning message